# How to remove elevation or box shadow in tab bar in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, shadow, tabbar, decoration

I am using tab bar in one of my screen. As you can see when I scroll there comes the elevation under the tab bar. I tried multiple ways to remove that, but can't. Do you guys have any idea on this ?
This is the code

```
TabBar(
          indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.tab,
          isScrollable: false,
          controller: _tabController,
          indicatorPadding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16.w, right: 16.w),
          tabs:[tab1(),tab2(),tab3(),
  ],
)
```

[image: Screen shot of the screen]

Comment: could you include your code too?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that it is not `TabBar` elevation. It is a shadow of `AppBar` as you are putting(*in my opinion*) `TabBar` inside `AppBar`. So do like this with your `AppBar`:

```
appBar: AppBar(
  ....,
  elevation: 0,
),
```